# How to find strings with xml pattern in batch file?

Tags: xml, batch-file

This question is about finding a string in a string that is xml-like. Batch will have problems with characters like "<", but thats not the end, my text also has "&" `echo %line%` with an & in it throws me a "`is not recognized as an external command`"
I am finding it hard to find an answer for this. I have a text file that contains an xml string like :

```
<ExampleTag1><error>Error message</error></ExampleTag1>
```

I wanted to use

```
set "line=<ExampleTag1><error>Error message</error></ExampleTag1>"
echo %line% | findstr /C:"ExampleTag1"
```

but its showing me error : `"< was unexpected at this time"`

I believe this is because `%line%` has "<" in it.

or actually is there a way to echo xml strings in batch?

Just `echo %line%` will show me the above error.

Can you guys help?

UPDATE : Actually I made a choice not to use batch to parse my text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch file - replace a string in an XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976734/windows-batch-file-replace-a-string-in-an-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "line=<ExampleTag1><error>Error message</error></ExampleTag"
echo "%line%" | findstr /C:"ExampleTag1"
ECHO %errorlevel%
GOTO :EOF
```

...assuming you want to set/examine `errorlevel`

Comment: Thanks. Actually this was exactly I was doing i.e. check errorlevel but I missed quotes around %line%. Having said that, in my text file, I also have symbols like "&" that made the batch file approach a mess. I gave up, I am using perl now.